# Elasticsearch filter by date range and other field

Tags: elasticsearch

i have query for grouping data by date and other field, and i want to filter it by range date and email, i have tried filter with only date, and it worked, after applying email query,it also work, but it shows all data.
this is my query looks like:

```
{
                    "_source": ["user_email","shipping_address.zipcode","eventtime"],
                    "query" : {
                        "bool":{
                            "filter": {
                                "range": {
                                    "eventtime":{
                                        "gt": start_date,
                                        "lt": end_date
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "should":{
                                "match_phrase_prefix" : {
                                    "user_email": "christea2045@yahoo.com"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },                    
                    "aggs": {
                        "group_by_date":{
                            "date_histogram":{
                                "field" : "eventtime",
                                "interval" : "1d"
                            },

                            "aggs":{
                                "group_shipzip":{
                                    "terms":{
                                        "field": "shipping_address.zipcode.keyword"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
```

Comment: range and email should be "and" or "or"?

Comment: it should be "and" @jaspreetchahal

Answer (score 0):

You need to add range and email in must clause

```
 "must": [
            {
               "range": {
                           "eventtime":{
                                        "gt": start_date,
                                        "lt": end_date
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            {
                              "match_phrase_prefix": {
                                                     "user_email": "abc1@yahoo.com"
                                                    }
                            }
                          ]
```

In your query only filter part is returning result. Since email is in should clause it will return document even if there is no match.

If you are doing a full text match on user_email then it is better to use term query on keyword field

```
{
          "term": {
            "user_email.keyword": {
              "value": "abc1@yahoo.com"
            }
          }
  }
``
```